# How to run macro if based on other cells which automatically changes by formula

Tags: vba, excel

As per subject, what I need is to run macro based on other cells.

Here is the case :

1. cells G3 until the end of row contains data used formula `=IF(B3="";"";(SUMIF('Incoming Goods'!$F$3:$F$1048576;'Current Stock'!B3;'Incoming Goods'!$M$3:$M$1048576)-(SUMIF('Outgoing Goods'!$D$4:$D$1048576;'Current Stock'!B3;'Outgoing Goods'!$J$4:$J$1048576))))`--> i need to convert this formula to VBA
2. cells H3 should contain : If G3.value = 0 then "Out of Stock", else " "

And this sheet must be calculate every time data in G3 change automatically or any additional data on this sheet.

Already tried this code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Current As Worksheet
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Target As Range

    Set Current = Worksheets("Current Stock")
    Set Rng1 = Current.Range("G:G")
    Set Target = Range("H:H")

    For Each Rng1 In Target
        If Rng1.Value2 = "0" Then
            Target.Value2 = "Out Of Stock"
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next 
End Sub
```

However, above code is Not working. Already try using `Private Sub Selection Change()` and `Private Sub Selection Change()` but still not working.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It always helps to specify what is not working. You are comparing the `.Value2` of a column to a string but you want to compare that of a single cell. Check out `.Offset` for that. Also, `Target` is already an object in  the `Change` and `SelectionChange` events so this code wouldn't work in these subs.

Comment: It seems to me (but I may have misunderstood question), that you would be better off by creating your own user defined function, instead of relying on worksheet calculate. Have you considered this option?

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA instead of formula?

Answer (score 0):

the answer to the first part is below:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(R[2]C[1]="""","""",(SUMIF('Incoming Goods'!R3C6:R1048576C6,'Current Stock'!R[2]C[1],'Incoming Goods'!R3C13:R1048576C13)-(SUMIF('Outgoing Goods'!R4C4:R1048576C4,'Current Stock'!R[2]C[1],'Outgoing Goods'!R4C10:R1048576C10))))"
```

handy tip: to convert any excel formula to code, hit the record macro button, then click on the cell, press F2 key, then press enter, and stop recording macro. The code will now be in its own module in the vba editor.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 200 Then
            Call YourMacroName
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```